# How to find the closest html tag to a certain character in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i am working on a project where i need to get the complete sentence between a html tag closest to a certain character.

**for example:**

in given example, if i search for **Mark**, then i want to print the complete sentence between the closest html tag.

```
<span>In paris (Mark Bartels) worked for about 10 years.</span>
```

is there a way to find the **closest html tag to a certain character** in php?

Comment: What do you mean a certain character? Do you mean the content of a tag? Can the character be in a tag? Please provide a specific example.

Comment: As PHP is executed on the server before the page gets rendered in the browser it has little concept of html or the content of your page. There is no, as far as I'm aware, equivalent method to the native jQuery function you mention. You might be able to do what you want if you enable output buffering of the page and then do some trick DOM manipulation / XPath queries etc

Comment: i have added example, please check

Comment: Did you tried something? You want to find out the tag name like <span> tag?

Comment: Is there any parent tag of this example which is having any class or id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```js
var elem = $('body').find('> :contains(Mark)').not('script, style, link');

$('pre').html(elem.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><span><h3>In paris (Mark Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3></span></div> <div><span><h3>In paris (Mary Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3></span></div>
<br><br><br>
Result string is:<br>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: i am sorry, it does not work for this case:                                              <div><span><h3>In paris (Mark Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3></span></div>
   <div><span><h3>In paris (Mary Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3></span></div>

Comment: ok, and one more thing,  what if the specific character appears more than once, then we need to print all the sentences which contains that specific character

Comment: for that you can use `.each()` loop.

Comment: Quite doable don't mind but that is another question and you can ask it.

Comment: it does not work for this case <div>
      <div><span><h3>In paris (Mark Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3></span></div> 
      <div><span><h3>In paris (Mary Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3></span></div>
     </div>

Comment: @Jai Why `$('body').find('>` and not `$('body').children('`